# VB.net XML Reading and writing

Tags: xml, vb.net

A few days ago i asked here on StackOverflow how te read XML data.

I got a great answer to that but i still have an issue.

This is my XML code in my TXT file:

```
<DataBase1>
<Info LastRow="7" />
<Row ID="1" Voornaam="Thomas" Achternaam="Ditto" Telefoon="04764" />
<Row ID="2" Voornaam="Bart" Achternaam="Soetens" Telefoon="123456" />
<Row ID="3" Voornaam="Koen" Achternaam="Baetens" Telefoon="789123" />
<Row ID="4" Voornaam="Ina" Achternaam="DV" Telefoon="147258" />
<Row ID="5" Voornaam="Saar" Achternaam="VDB" Telefoon="852369" />
<Row ID="6" Voornaam="erwin" Achternaam="vanden" Telefoon="111111" />
<Row ID="7" Voornaam="lol" Achternaam="broek" Telefoon="000111" />
</DataBase1>
<DataBase2>
<Info LastRow="7">
    <Lastupdated Date="20180617" ID="1" />
    <Lastupdated Date="20180607" ID="2" />
    <Lastupdated Date="20180613" ID="3" />
    <Lastupdated Date="20180613" ID="4" />
    <Lastupdated Date="20180611" ID="5" />
    <Lastupdated Date="20180601" ID="6" />
    <Lastupdated Date="20180605" ID="7" />
</Info>
<Row ID="1" Job="Programmer" />
<Row ID="2" Job="Constructor" />
<Row ID="3" Job="Teacher" />
<Row ID="4" Job="Cop" />
<Row ID="5" Job="Pimp" />
<Row ID="6" Job="No job" />
<Row ID="7" Job="Swimmer" />
</DataBase2>
```

I can read everything with this VB.net code:

```
If File.Exists("c:/CPS/VB-XML.txt") Then
            Dim x = XElement.Load("c:/CPS/E-Journal.txt")
            LastRow = x.<Info>.@LastRow
            Dim ele As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = x.Descendants("Row")

            For Each RStatus As XElement In ele
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(RStatus.Attribute("ID").Value,
                                       RStatus.Attribute("Voornaam").Value,
                                       RStatus.Attribute("Achternaam").Value,
                                       RStatus.Attribute("Telefoon").Value)

            Next

        Else
            File.Create("c:/CPS/VB-XML.txt")
        End If
```

And here is problem/question 1: X in the VB.net script reads the data from Database1 but how to let it read from Database2. Can someone help me??

Question 2: How to add rows in Database1 and/or Database2 and also how to add a Lastupdated record in the Info section and save it back again in my txt file.

Question 3: How to edit information based in the ID.

I know it's a lot probably not the best way to read/handle XML.

Please help

Comment: I suggest that instead of having `<Database1>` and `<Database2>` you should use `<Database ID="1">` and `<Database ID="2">`, and surround the whole thing with `<Databases>` and `</Databases>`.

Comment: If you are in control of the XML format I suggest you follow Andrew's suggestion. This makes it possible (or at least easier) to perform XML Serialization, giving you the option to read and modify the XML in an object-oriented manner (which is much easier).

Comment: Do you just need `XElement.Parse`?

Comment: Glad you managed to find a solution! However please do not put it in your question. It makes it harder to find and makes it less apparent that the question has been solved. Instead, ask @AndrewMorton to write his comment in an answer (or you can write one yourself) and accept it so that you clearly indicate to others that this solved your problem. Thank you!

Comment: @VisualVincent one problem is solved, wouldn't be better to make an answer post after the 2 other problems are solved??

Comment: This is a good example of why multi-questions are actually considered too broad at Stack Overflow. It makes it much harder to answer as you might not be able to answer all of them. A question should really only focus on **one** question/problem at a time.

Comment: Anyway, with your change you should really look into XML Serialization like I mentioned before. It lets you create classes/types for managing the data, which makes it **much** easier to modify through code. Here's a good article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic parsing of the xml that puts the data into a dataset with one table for each database.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Data

Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim databases As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("DataBase")).ToList()

        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        For Each database As XElement In databases
            Dim newTable As New DataTable(database.Name.LocalName)
            ds.Tables.Add(newTable)
            Dim first As Boolean = True

            For Each row As XElement In database.Descendants("Row")
                If first = True Then
                    first = False

                    For Each Attribute In row.Attributes()
                        newTable.Columns.Add(Attribute.Name.LocalName, GetType(String))
                    Next
                End If
                Dim newRow As DataRow = newTable.Rows.Add()
                For Each Attribute In row.Attributes()
                    newRow(Attribute.Name.LocalName) = Attribute.Value
                Next
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```